# TypeError: cb is not a function

Tags: javascript, passport-local

So when I try to register using this code

```
router.post(
  "/register",
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password, email, number, address } = req.body.user;
    const user = new User({
      email,
      username,
      number,
      address,
      isVerified: false,
    });
    const registredUser = await User.register(user, username, password);
    req.login(registredUser, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      console.log(registredUser);
      req.flash("success", "Dobro došli na About Women!");
      res.redirect("users/confirm");
    });
  })
);
```

it flashes error in the title. I tried doing everything even referencing to my old code but none of it worked. This is log I get from console:

```
node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:247
    promise.then((result) => cb(null, result)).catch((err) => cb(err));
                                                              ^

TypeError: cb is not a function
```

How can I fix it? Also I am using passport for user registration.

Comment: There is no `cb` in the code you posted. Look at the stack and see who expected a `cb` parameter.

Comment: Here is the console log node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:247
    promise.then((result) => cb(null, result)).catch((err) => cb(err));
                                                              ^

TypeError: cb is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message points to line 247 of index.js in the passport-local-mongoose package.  See https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/main/index.js#L247

That is in the register function:

```
schema.statics.register = function (user, password, cb) {
```

The arguments are expected to be user, password, and callback.  You are passing user, username, and password, so at line 247 it is trying to use the password as a callback function, which fails with the error message you noted.